# Clear a JLabel with a Jbutton

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, jlabel

I am actually a beginner in Java Programming (on eclipse and without netbeans), and want to clear a JLabel presents in a JFrame by clicking a JButton without removing the JButton present at the top of this frame.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.BoundedRangeModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ButtonTest extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
  private JButton ouvrirButton = new JButton("Ouvrir");
  private JButton retirerButton = new JButton("Retirer");
  private JButton ajouterButton = new JButton("Ajouter");

public ButtonTest() {
  add(ouvrirButton);
  add(retirerButton);
  add(ajouterButton);

ouvrirButton.addActionListener(this);
retirerButton.addActionListener(this);
ajouterButton.addActionListener(this);}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
 Object source = evt.getSource();
 Color color = getBackground();

// ACTION Button "OUVRIR"
// I WANT TO REMOVE THIS JLABEL TEXT WHEN I CLICK FOR EXEMPLE ON
// OR "RETIRER"

if (source == ouvrirButton)
{ 
    color = Color.yellow;
    JLabel lab1 = new JLabel("Text", JLabel.LEFT);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
    add(lab1 = new JLabel("INVENTAIRE : "));
    lab1.setBounds(20, 15, 500, 100);
}
else if (source == retirerButton)
        color = Color.red;
else if (source == ajouterButton)
    color = Color.red;
setBackground(color);
repaint();
}

// The main

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // NOM DE LA FENETRE
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Programme ");

frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    System.exit(0);
  }
});

Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
contentPane.add(new ButtonTest());
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
frame.setSize(1300, 700);
frame.setVisible(true);    
}
}
```

I tried   .setText("")  but it doesn't work... Please help me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried .setText("") but it doesn't work...

Yes it does. The problem is you create the label in the ActionListener so that label reference is only valid in the block of code that created it.

You need to create the label as an instance variable (the way you did  for all you buttons) and add the label to the fame at the same time you add the buttons to the panel.

Then you will be able to access the label in the ActionListener and change the text.